# Scraping Value after Euro Symbol (Scrapy-Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

i need the a selector to scrape the value after the euro symbol (\u20ac).

```
<Selector xpath='//*[@class="col-sm-4"]/text()' data=u'\r\n\t\t            \u20ac 30.000,00'>
```

I tried dozens of variations that i have found here on stackoverflow and elsewere but i cant get it.

Sides like https://regexr.com/ show me that something like this:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="col-sm-4"]/text()').re('(\u20ac).\d*.\d*.\d*')
```

should work, but it doesnt.

EDIT: Here a example link of Data that i would like to scrape: https://www.firmenabc.at/manfred-jungwirth-montagen_MoKY

Would appreciate help!

Michael

Comment: Hope my answer helped you, if it id, please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: Can you provide here a chunk of elements to work with. You neither reveal the link nor any sufficient resources to work on it. It's hard to answer without testing it practically.

Comment: your right Shahin - i updated a sample link - also here: https://www.firmenabc.at/manfred-jungwirth-montagen_MoKY

Comment: Thanks for updating your question to bring the clarity. However, I can't find any amount on that page which is close to 30.000,00;rather, this is what I can see € 150,000.00. Lead me to find the location of that amount first. Thanks.

Comment: this firm was just an example, as the one with € 30.000,00 - so a hint for scraping the € amount of this firm is appreciated as for every other firm of firmenabc.at. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="col-sm-4"]/text()').re(u'\u20ac\s*(\d+[\d\.,]+)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex you are looking for. If you want to match `\u20ac` literally you need to prefix it with a `\`, the following variant: `\u20ac|\\u20ac` will match both € and \u20ac:

`(\u20ac|\\u20ac)\s+.\d*.\d*.\d*`

Missing was also a `\s+`. `\s` specifies you want to match a white space, `\s+` specifies you want to match multiple white space (notice there is white space between \u20ac and the value, 30.000,00)

Notice though that this will capture only the `€` symbol (capture groups are composed of closed parentheses `()`, i.e. (*ANYTHING BETWEEN THIS WILL BE CAPTURED*)

So I believe what you want is:

`\u20ac|\\u20ac\s+(\d*.*)` - Here, we're surrounding `.\d*.*` with `()` therefore capturing that value instead of the `€` symbol.

Repeating `.\d*` is redundant, you already indicated you want to match every ocassion of it by writing it previously: `\d` and suffixing it a `*`.

Lastly, I recommend you play around with regex using https://www.regex101.com - It's a great tool and will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: i learned a lot from your answer - thanks for that! - unfortunately "\u20ac|\\u20ac\s+(\d*.*)" - or variations, arent working. Maybe it has something to do with the withespaces before the € symbol? (\r\n\t\t            \u20ac...)

Comment: Try this ``\s+(\d*.*)``